# Sorting multiple lists on the basis of common field

Tags: c#, linq

I have a structure of classes like this.

```
public class Video
{
   public string URL { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }

}

public class Product
{
    public List<Video> videoList { get; set; }
    public List<Image> imageList { get; set; }
}
```

I need to display the video and images sorted by value in the field order from a consolidated list of videos and images.

**What I tried**:

1. I cast both the lists to list of objects and concatenated it.

Problem: I lost the field `Order` so was unable to sort.

2. I cast `List<Video>` to `List<Images>` and then concatenated it.

Problem: I won't get the `URL` of the video.

Please advise on how to achieve the same.
Please note that the classes in the example are only for illustration. In actual, all the classes have more than 20 of fields.

**Edit 1**:

This is legacy code and the `Order` field have different sources. So, can not follow the approach suggested by @jcruz

Comment: What is the relationship between images to videos or vise versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could still use the Cast as Object approach, but making it a part of an anonymous type. For instance,

```
var result = product.videoList.Select(x=> new {Data = (object)x,Order=x.Order})
                 .Concat(product.imageList.Select(c=>new {Data = (object)c,Order=c.Order}))
                 .OrderBy(x=>x.Order);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a common `interface` for your image and video objects. This would hold any common properties and allow you to access and sort based off of it.

```
public interface IMedia
{
    public int Order;
}

public class Video : IMedia
{
   public string URL { get; set; }
   public int Order { get; set; }
}

public class Image : IMedia
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

Then use a `List<IMedia>` instead and you will be able to sort of the interface field.

```
List<IMedia> list = new List<IMedia>();
list.OrderBy(i => i.Order);
```

HTH

Comment: Sorry it was my fault that I failed to provide an essential limitation. I have updated my question.

Comment: @NutsAndBolts Which code do you have access to change?

Comment: I can only add fields. Cannot modify it in any other way.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to enhace @jcruz answer, according you cannot modify Image and Video classes. I hope you can derive from them (they are not sealed) and assuming they have a construtor like `public Video(Video origin) {...}` (or you can restore their state with their's constructors) try this or something like this:

```
public class Video
{
    public string URL { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }

}

public class Product
{
    public List<Video> videoList { get; set; }
    public List<Image> imageList { get; set; }

    public List<IOrdered> OrderedStuff => 
        videoList
        .Select(x => new VideoInterfaced(x) as IOrdered)
        .Union(imageList.Select(x => new ImageInterfaced(x) as IOrdered))
        .OrderBy(x => x.Order)
        .ToList();
}


public interface IOrdered
{
    int Order { get; set; }
}

public class VideoInterfaced : Video, IOrdered
{
    public VideoInterfaced(Video origin) : base(origin)
    {
        //...
    }
}

public class ImageInterfaced : Image, IOrdered
{
    public ImageInterfaced(Image origin) : base(origin)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This example is assuming that the Image to Video is 1 to 1.

```
public class ProductData
{
    public Video Video {get;set;}
    public Image Image {get;set;}
}

public IDictionary<int,ProductData> AggrigateData(List<Video> videos, List<Image> images)
{
    var orderedSet = images.OrderBy(image => image.Order);
    return videos.ToDictonary(video => video.Order, video => new ProductData {Video = video, Image = orderedSet.FirstOrDefault(image => image.Order == video.Order))}
}
```